# How to use Unicode hex escape in :s/// replacement string in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want to use a hexadecimal Unicode escape in the replacement string of a substitution command, i.e., with the example character U+20AC:

```
:s#something#\x{20AC}#g
```

The above example doesn't work, because it uses Perl syntax in the replacement string, but I want this to work in Vim, and I want it to work for many different other possible Unicode characters too, specified by their hexadecimal value (2 or 4 digits or possibly even more). Since this is a series of substitution statements that will be generated by a script, I would like the substitution statements itself to be ASCII-only, as that is easier to work with. I think there must be a proper syntax for this, but I just cannot find it. \%u20AC works in the search pattern, but not in the replacement string. As this is not done interactively, the CTRL-V + 4 hex digits method won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:s#something#\=nr2char(0x20AC)#g`

See `:help sub-replace-expression` and `:help nr2char()` in Vim.

Or, if `20AC` is really a constant, you can type `:` `s` `#` `something` `#` `<Ctrl-V>` `u` `20AC` `#` `g` `<Enter>`, giving

`:s#something#€#g`

See `:help i_ctrl-v` in Vim.

Comment: Okay, this is slightly more readable than what I found myself, although strictly speaking a bit more complicated since it uses a function call. The ctrl-V method was not applicable, I already mentioned it in the question. But it might be useful for other readers.

Comment: In a script you can write `execute "s#something#\u20AC#g"`. The `\u` is interpreted because it appears in a doublequoted string, and the result is then interpreted by `execute`.

Comment: That would be in a Vim script. I was thinking of a Perl script generating Vim commands (from some input file specifying mappings) to be executed by @x in Vim. But it's also a good tip, thanks. (And yeah, I could do the whole substitution in Perl, but I don't want to do it on every line, so I do that bit interactively. I just was surprised that there was no easy direct way to do it.)

Comment: @x executes a Vim script. Have your Perl program generate the `execute` command.

Comment: I thought it just executes the buffer contents as a key mapping? Anyway, I'll read up on that, thanks.

Comment: In normal mode, `@` executes the contents of a register as a sequence of keys. In command mode, `:@` executes the contents of a register as a script.

Answer (score 1):

After some more doc reading, I found at least one, very elaborate way to do this, using a substution expression:

```
:s#something#\="\<Char-0x20AC>"#g
```

I prefer it because it is built right into the parser, instead of using a Vimscript function call.

One would hope there is an easier (more direct) way to do this though.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are fine; string interpolation via `:execute` is a method that is particularly suited to scripting, so I'm mentioning that as well.

You can use the [`:help <Char>`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3CChar%3E) notation within double-quoted strings:

```
let char = "\<Char-0x20AC>"
execute 's#something#' . char . '#g'
```

Or convert a number via `nr2char()`:

```
let value = 0x20AC
execute 's#something#' . nr2char(value) . '#g'
```